# Solve for x(t) in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I have the following matlab code:

```
load = 130;
fr = 5.56;
mass = 2.5;
len = 0.75;
diam = 36/1000;
pa = 135;
pec = 100;
mc = 1.28;
md = 1.20;
xec1 = 0.5;
xmax = 0.5;
xep2 = 0.025;

syms t
x = sym('x(t)');

p1 = pec*(xec1/x)^md;
p2 = pa*((xmax-xep2)/(x+len-xep2))^mc;

fp = (p1-p2)*pi*diam^2/4;

eqn = simplify((fp - fr - load)/mass) == diff(diff(x));
```

What I'm really attempting to do is figure out what x(t) is, since on 1 side of the equation I 2 instances of x(t) (in p1 and p2) and in the other I have x''(t).

In theory, one would have to integrate twice on both sides in respect to t to get this. However, how is this achievable through matlab? Am I taking the wrong approach here?

For a little context just in case, eqn is Newton's second law replacing acceleration for the second derivative of position in time and p1 and p2 are two pressures translated to forces but are related to position as well.

**EDIT:** I'm looking for the symbolic answer.

Comment: if you are interested in a numerical answer (all the terms have values), why are you solving symbolically and not using ode23?

Comment: @rodrigocf: can you please clarify if you are looking for a numerical or symbolic answer?

Comment: @edwinksl I'm looking for the symbolic answer.

Comment: @rodrigocf I just tried to look for a symbolic answer, but unfortunately MATLAB says an explicit solution could not be found and returns an implicit solution that is not particularly helpful. A numerical solution may be more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the ODE symbolically by using `diff` and `dsolve`. The code to do this is:

```
load = 130;
fr = 5.56;
mass = 2.5;
len = 0.75;
diam = 36/1000;
pa = 135;
pec = 100;
mc = 1.28;
md = 1.20;
xec1 = 0.5;
xmax = 0.5;
xep2 = 0.025;

syms x(t)

p1 = pec*(xec1/x)^md;
p2 = pa*((xmax-xep2)/(x+len-xep2))^mc;
fp = (p1-p2)*pi*diam^2/4;
xpp = (fp - fr - load)/mass;

x(t) = dsolve(diff(x,t,2) == xpp);
x(t) = simplify(x(t));
x(t)
```

For this particular ODE, MATLAB emits a warning that says `Warning: Explicit solution could not be found; implicit solution returned.` and the implicit solution is not particularly useful. I would recommend solving it numerically with appropriate initial conditions.